# PC connected to TV via VGA & audio in, plays Youtube videos ok but lags when full screen

Tags: tv, vga, streaming

I managed to connect my PC running Windows XP SP3 to my LCD TV with VGA and audio in for the sound. Everything seems ok, there is no lag with the mouse or when watching videos on Youtube, iPlayer, etc. until I put the videos in full screen mode. The videos appear to lag slightly. What possible solutions are there to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: are all the lagging fullscreen videos flash (or at least browser) videos?  do video files playback without the lag?  do they lag if you watch them in fullscreen on a regular monitor?

Comment: And if they do lag in fullscreen on a regular monitor, how does your monitor's resolution compare to your TV's?

Comment: They are fine on a regular monitor. And I take that Youtube and BBC iPlayer are flash. Also Im using the same resolution.

Comment: Is your desktop cloned/extended? If so, set it to single (just the TV).

Comment: @wombart: the [video-streaming] tag has been removed; please don't roll it back into existence again.  add a separate [video] tag if you want to specify video streaming.  i still think this question should be tagged [windows-xp] instead of [pc] -- [pc] is a fairly useless tag.

Comment: Thanks, however I do already have it set as single.

Answer (score 0):

What graphics chip are you using?  All recent onboard graphics and discrete graphics cards (at least from the last 5 or 6 years) should hardware-accelerate decoding of Flash video.  This should allow you to play Flash video without any lag, even when using low-powered CPUs.

For this to work, make sure you have the latest graphics drivers installed, as well as [Flash Player 10.1](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/systemreqs/) or later.